# Cambiar el nombre de una app en android xamarin forms

Tags: formularios, xamarin, android-manifest

Como puedo cambiar el nombre de una aplicación, el nombre que aparece bajo el icono cuando se va a abrir una app en el launcher de android.

He agregado en la etiqueta app

```
<application android:label="Nombre App">
```

Pero no ha cambiado el nombre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifica el atributo Label en tu MainActivity.

```
[Activity(Label = "NombreDeMiApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity
{
    ...
}
```